# How to treat borderline duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

Examples here:
[Does the "@" symbol have a name?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24697/does-the-symbol-have-a-name/24700#comment-41992)
Edgar Gonzalez asks specifically for a one-word name.

[What do you call a noun that precedes and describes another noun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24680/what-do-you-call-a-noun-that-precedes-and-describes-another-noun) In addition to the original question, Acorn asks if it is still a noun or adjective.

This can be solved by adding an answer in the first, authentic question. This answer can cover the subtleties of the borderline duplicate. However this creates other problem because you risk writing about things that stray away from the original question.

notes:
-the moderator adds "possible duplicate" next to the link, but this contradicts the "exact duplicate" official reason
-users can have different opinions about whether it is nuanced or not. It's a matter of how you understand the language.

Comment: Regarding the sideswipe about "possible/exact duplicate", I've always understood that "possible" (as shown to all viewers of the page) simply reflects the fact that thus far less than 5 people have flagged it for closure. At the "system" level, the assessment is only provisional, no matter how strongly the individuals flagging it may happen to feel. Plus it would be ridiculous to display *Possible exact duplicate of xxxx, in the opinion of - xxxx*.

Answer (score 2):

Those questions are considered duplicates because the answer to one question is also the answer to the other question.
In the specific, the most voted answer for [What is the word that denotes the words preceding these nouns?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15700/what-is-the-word-that-denotes-the-words-preceding-these-nouns) reports the following sentence:

> The word I hear most is *noun adjective*, while *attributive noun* and *noun adjunct* sound equally appropriate and current.

The answer I gave for that question is:

> *Computer*, in *computer vision*, is a modifier, which is a word (especially an adjective or noun used attributively), that restricts or adds to the sense of a head noun.

This means that a modifier could be a noun, as in *computer vision*, or an adjective, as in *beautiful house*. 
The answer to the second question asked in [What do you call a noun that precedes and describes another noun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24680/what-do-you-call-a-noun-that-precedes-and-describes-another-noun) has been already answered in the answers for the other question.

The text that you find at the beginning of a question closed as duplicate is not added by any moderators; it's added by the system to report which question has been duplicated.
If you would be able to edit a closed question (I am not sure if all users have that possibility), you would notice there is a comment saying: `<!-- End of automatically inserted text -->` added after the text reporting the link to the duplicated question.

Comment: Anyway, I think it's always better to add extended, comprehensive and qualitative answers.